# Using LIKE for two different columns doesn't return desired results

Tags: sql-server

I have a table (carriers) I'm searching. I'm using LIKE to query the DB. I'm querying two columns (cName,code) in that one table and then checking to see if it's active. If so, return the result. My problem is that if I do a search for code "ABCD" I get nothing returned (which is correct cause ABCD is inactive. When I search the carrier name of ABCD (American Bu...). I get a record returned (which is wrong cause the customer is inactive). How do I force sql to NOT show me inactive carriers?
Here's my sql:

```
SELECT carrierID, cName, code 
FROM carriers 
WHERE 
  (
    cName LIKE '%" & replace(q,"'","''") & "%' 
    OR code LIKE '%" & replace(q,"'","''") & "%'
  ) 
  AND active='True'
```

Comment: I don't think your concatenation works like that;

Comment: I'm using classic asp and that's how you concatenate.

Comment: You have to use dynamic sql, if you want to concatenate values to your LIKE condition

Comment: that's a dynamic sql string. The code originates in a classic asp page. I could've just wrote cName LIKE '%American B%' OR code LIKE '%American B%' AND active='True'

Comment: It is hard to see why your query fails, please see this [link on How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: the problem is that active should supersede everything else. If it's not active, then don't show. That's not what is happening. The active part only seems to apply to the code column and not the cName column. cName returns records whether active or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are constructing the SQL on the web-server or client.

```
Declare mySQL as String = "SELECT carrierID, cName, code FROM carriers WHERE CharIndex('[getSearch]',cName) + CharIndex('[getSearch]',code) > 0 and active='True'"
mySQL = Replace(mySQL,"[getSearch]",replace(q,"'","''"))
```

fyi CharIndex is faster than LIKE

Comment: I don't know if I fully believe [this one-off test I've seen you cite](http://cc.davelozinski.com/sql/like-vs-substring-vs-leftright-vs-charindex) will be applicable in other scenarios. For starters, most people aren't doing things like `(aClusteredIndexedColumn like @WhatToLookFor + '%' or aClusteredIndexedColumn like '%' + @WhatToLookFor)`, or only clearing buffer pool etc. at the beginning of all the tests and then running the `LIKE` test first (which means it pays the cost of loading the data into the buffer pool). On quick glance, test seems kind of slanted to me.

Comment: @AaronBertrand  I doubted it too so I ran a series of tests on 65MM rows.  of data.  CharIndex was consistantly  faster 50 - 120% faster  This is the post that changed my mind http://cc.davelozinski.com/sql/like-vs-substring-vs-leftright-vs-charindex

Comment: Yeah that's the same link I put in my comment. Do you have any other published evidence of this? Again, the tests in that specific article don't seem fair, and if you ran your tests based on the same framework...

Comment: @AaronBertrand  It is my understanding that LIKE will use indexes for prefix scans only.  Regarding my tests, I didn't get the same results as published, yet I was VERY satisfied.   I did google "which is faster charindex or like" an there are arguments and dogmas on both sides of the fence.  Perhaps this question would make a good bounty.

Answer (score 0):

I have created an example below for your query.  As long as you supply values in this format, you can expect results.  I believe there is something wrong with your concatenation.  You may try to check using `SQL Profiler` to see what you are sending to SQL server.

```
CREATE TABLE carriers
(
    carrierID INT
    , cName     VARCHAR(50)
    , code      VARCHAR(50)
    , active    VARCHAR(5)
)
GO

INSERT INTO carriers VALUES (1, 'ABCD', 'XYZ', 'False')
INSERT INTO carriers VALUES (2, 'test', 'abcd', 'False')
INSERT INTO carriers VALUES (3, 'ABCD2', 'XYZ', 'True')
INSERT INTO carriers VALUES (4, 'test2', 'abcd2', 'True')

SELECT carrierID, cName, code
FROM carriers
WHERE
    (
            cName   LIKE '%ABCD%'
            OR code LIKE '%ABCD%'
    )
    AND active='True'
```

Comment: nothing wrong with my concatenation. that's a dynamic sql string. The code originates in a classic asp page. I could've just wrote cName LIKE '%American B%' OR code LIKE '%American B%' AND active='True' <-- this would return something when it should return nothing because this carriers' active='false'

Comment: You may take my script, add your input data and let this fail to let us know where your query fails...